# Tlauncher wont open

Tags: minecraft, executable

I installed TLauncher , it worked well
but when I close it I can't open it again

and when i try to open with openjdk it says that it's not marked as executable
:(
pliz help
and when I only click on it normally it open a file
pliiiz help